# Facebook sharing does not parse any links on my site other than homepage

Tags: web-scraping, facebook-opengraph

I have a personal website at http://deanattali.com/

A few days ago I shared my site on my feed and everything was ok.  Now whenever I try to share any other page, Facebook does not parse it and simply ignores it.

I tried the Open Graph Object Debugger tool and it always returns "Error Linting URL    An internal error occurred while linting the URL."

For example, try any of the following URLs: 
http://deanattali.com/aboutme
http://deanattali.com/2015/03/12/beautiful-jekyll-how-to-build-a-site-in-minutes/

I even tried taking an HTML page from a similar site and copying the exact same HTML onto my site, and the parser worked for the other site but not for mine

Page on other site that works: http://keshinid.github.io/2015-02-26-flake-it-till-you-make-it/
Page on my site with identical HTML that doesn't work: http://deanattali.com/test

This is very frustrating, the error is very vague.

When I try to click on the link to see what the scraper sees on FB's debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) it says "Document returned no data"

Another point worth mentioning is that this is a GitHub Pages website, with URL daattali.github.io and I have a CNAME to deanattali.com (I'm not sure if that matters at all)

I'm very lost, thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who will ever run into this problem in the future: a bandage fix seems to be to append `?fbrefresh=anystring` to the URL. It looks like when there is a `fbrefresh` param in the query string, it works fine (doesn't matter what the value of the parameter is).  Not sure what the underlying cause is, whether this is a bug or not.